# QWidget::setEnabled(false) fails 2 times out of 10 in debug version only

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

First, it sort of complicates debugging but I can live with that. What's worse, I'm afraid there's a race condition somewhere in Qt internals that would make the thing fail in release version too in a situation I can not predict nor run into accidentally.

The (pseudo)code goes roughly like this:

```
class MyCheckBox : public QCheckBox
{
public slots:
    void onClicked();
};

MyCheckBox::MyCheckBox()
{
    connect(this, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &MyCheckBox::onClicked);
}

void MyCheckBox::onClicked()
{
    qDebug() << "onClicked";
    setEnabled(false);
}
```

Log says `onClicked()` gets called but the button stays enabled. Qt 5.7, Windows 7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has that happened to you only with your current project or in other projects have you had the same problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc This is my first Qt project.

Comment: How did you check that the widget is still enabled? Did you add a debug statement  `qDebug() << "enabled:" << isEnabled(); ` after the call to `setEnabled`?

Comment: If it is your first project please create a new one and check if it is the same, or at least share your complete project. The error can not only happen in the declaration and the slots, it could be in other parts of the project.

Comment: @Corristo I checked it empirically: it's painted enabled and accepts input.

Comment: @sigil Can you try what the output of the debugging statement I posted earlier is. The [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) explicitly states "*In general an enabled widget handles keyboard and mouse events; a disabled widget does not. An exception is made with QAbstractButton.*"
So maybe it is disabled, but the it doesn't show the behavior you expect from a disabled `MyCheckBox`.